# header row every 5 rows in a cakephp paginate table

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

How can you put a header row every 5 rows in a cakephp paginate table ?

I want all rows on the same page  so I have it set to paginate every 100 rows.  I have only 40 rows so they show on one page which is what I want but the header is at top and not visible when user scrolls. (I know that is why they have to paginate but I want all rows on the same page).

With straight up PHP this is no problem, just do a count every 5 rows and insert header row; but how do I do this with CakePHP?

I've been fiddling with paginate in my controller and view but its hard to figure the mix of html and php with the `:`

Any ideas?

Comment: CakePHP *is* PHP. In your view you're looping to output rows, no?

Comment: Ok, so no 'cakey' way to do it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion that there is no 'cakey' way to do this was helpful and steered me back to plain old php for solution.

I ended up doing simple if else loop using a row counter uses the Controller paginator counter that would insert a header row every x rows.

```
<?php 
$count = $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => '{:count}'));
$i = 0;
foreach ($cards as $card) {
     $count++;
     if($count%10==0){
     //&& ($count == 30 || $count == 40 || $count == 50)
    INSERT HEADER ROW (using html)
            INSERT DATA ROW  (using html and php)   
    } else {    
            INSERT DATA ROW (using html and php)
            }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a fixed header?  That seems more logical than making 10 headers.

Comment: With many records on page, header at top is hidden when user scrolls down page .. so want to give headers every x rows so user can see what column is what.

another application of this view setup is, for example, putting advertisements every x rows.

i thought cakephp paginate or other function might have this variable counting ability which could be hooked in view.

So, solution is to 'break' cakephp baked view (the way cake view loop appears fresh after baking) and use plain php loop and counter that every x rows insert a header row.

Comment: I meant a fixed header like that: http://www.tablefixedheader.com/demonstration/     You can make one with css.

Comment: Ah, I see .. I didn't say I modified view already to remove that embedded scrollable table deal .. don't like those .. table is all scrunched up in little window, have to scroll hor and ver back and forth to see everthing.. thanks fro suggestion though.